# Using multiple commands in a dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My Dockerfile contents are as follows:

```
FROM amd64/ubuntu:xenial-20180726

ARG GETH_REPO="https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum"
ARG GETH_VERSION="v1.8.12"


CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "git clone ${GETH_REPO} && \ 
        cd go-ethereum && \
        git fetch origin ${GETH_VERSION} && \
        git checkout ${GETH_VERSION} && \
        make geth && \
        touch /var/log/geth_log"]
```

Basically, I want to download from the repository and build. 
However, when I run the created image I get the following error

```
$ docker run -it <imageid>
/bin/sh: 1: [/bin/bash,: not found
```

I have made sure that I can execute these operations by logging into the running container.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json syntax is invalid, so docker is running it as a string with a shell, instead of execing it. There's nothing in your command that requires bash, so you can use the default /bin/sh with the string syntax:

```
FROM amd64/ubuntu:xenial-20180726

ARG GETH_REPO="https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum"
ARG GETH_VERSION="v1.8.12"

RUN git clone ${GETH_REPO} && \ 
        cd go-ethereum && \
        git fetch origin ${GETH_VERSION} && \
        git checkout ${GETH_VERSION} && \
        make geth && \
        touch /var/log/geth_log
```

Note that all of your steps are being run as the default start command for the container, rather than being performed at build time. You likely want to replace CMD with RUN.

Comment: I tried that and I get the following error

`
$ docker run -it 19bd08d6fa2d
You must specify a repository to clone.

usage: git clone [<options>] [--] <repo> [<dir>]
`
Is there a need to provide the value of `GETH_REPO` during run? (default value provided)

Comment: Build args only apply at build time. Do you want these commands to run at build time when you make the image, or at run time every time you create the container?